# Windows 2003 SP1 terminal server printers Disappear after reboot - HP laserjet 4240

Tags: windows-server-2003, drivers

had working PCL6 laserjet 4240 driver.  needed to downgrade to PCl5, tried but did not get clean install.  tried again and it seemed to work (this is 2003 enterprise terminal server SP2)  Have over 40 working laserjets (5, 4000, 4100 and 18 of the 4240)  After normal nightly reboot the 18 4240 printers were 'gone'.  Worked w/Microsoft who said bad HP driver issues - weird since they work on other terminal servers.  downloaded latest version, etc. from HP site and can NOT get to work.  As soon as I install, then do a Net Stop Spool and Net Start Spooler the printer is 'gone'.

Current workaround is to use HP 4000 PCL5 drivers for all of these 4240 printers.

Comment: Are they added as Local Printers or Network Printers?

Answer (score 0):

It sure sounds like you have a driver issue.  Have you tried the [HP PCL5 univeral print drivers](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?prodNameId=503519&locale=en_US&taskId=135&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=503548)?  I've found that the UPD driver is generally more stable than the specific printer drivers- almost across the board.